# incompatible types: AccessControlContext cannot be converted to ECartHomeActivity(MainActivity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm getting the error in this part of the Activtiy(SearchActivity.java):

```
// Whenever a view in your cart is clicked
shoppinListAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
             Utils.switchFragmentWithAnimation(
                                    R.id.frag_container,
                                    new ProductDetailsFragment("", position, true),
                                    ((ECartHomeActivity) (getContext())), null,
                                    Utils.AnimationType.SLIDE_LEFT);
                                   // ECartHomeActivity is the MainActivity
           }
});
```

and this is the method of Utils class which is used in the Activity:

```
public static void switchFragmentWithAnimation(int id, Fragment fragment,
            FragmentActivity activity, String TAG, AnimationType transitionStyle) {

  FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

  if (transitionStyle != null) {
    switch (transitionStyle) {
       case SLIDE_UP:
         // Enter from Up
         fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up,
                        R.anim.slide_out_up);

         break;

       case SLIDE_LEFT:
         // Enter from left
         fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left,
                        R.anim.slide_out_left);

         break;

       default:
         break;
    }
  }

  CURRENT_TAG = TAG;

  fragmentTransaction.replace(id, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

This code I have Copy pasted from one of my fragments into this Searched_Product_Activtiy.java. It works fine in the fragments.

Comment: don't paste code as image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to convert ECartHomeActivity as a context with `((ECartHomeActivity) (getContext())` which will not work because it's a class not an Activity instance.

You can use `SearchActivity.this` as the Activity for the Utils but change the `activity` parameter to **Activity** like this:

```
public static void switchFragmentWithAnimation(int id, Fragment fragment,
            Activity activity, String TAG, AnimationType transitionStyle) {
}
```

But that's probably not you want, I guess you want to switch the Fragment in MainActivity. If this what you intended, you should use `startActivityForResult()` from the MainActivity. To do that, first you need to start the ActivitySearch from your MainActivity:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
...
public void startSearch() {  
  Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySearch.class);  
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Second, override `onActivityResult()` in MainActivity to receive the result from ActivitySearch:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // Check which request we're responding to
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      // Call your util here
      Utils.switchFragmentWithAnimation(
               R.id.frag_container,
               new ProductDetailsFragment("", position, true),
               MainActivity.this, null,
               Utils.AnimationType.SLIDE_LEFT);

    }
  }
}
```

Last, in ActivitySearch, whenever you click the item on search you need to send the result to MainActivity:

```
shoppinListAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
          Intent intent=new Intent();
          // send data if you want
          //intent.putExtra("DATA", yourdata);  
          setResult(MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE, intent);  
          finish(); // close the SearchActivity
       }
```

Comment: where should I call the startSearch() ? If I'm calling it in the MainActivtiy's onCreate() method then at the start of the app instead of MainActivity, SearchActivity is being called. And also whenever I'm clicking on the item instead of fragment, MainActivity is opening

Comment: You need to calling `startSearch()` whenever you want to do the searching. Could be when clicking a button search or menu search.